# Cannot run Graphviz from C# as new process

Tags: c#, process, png, graphviz

I create a .dot file in the bin folder of GraphViz.

If I execute from command line: `dot -Tpng -o graph.png -graph.dot` 
it creates a png image, but if I run it within C# the png file is not created. The program rus as admin. (check code below)

```
using (var dot = new Process())
{
    dot.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // Run process as admin.
    dot.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe";
    dot.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Tpng -o graph.png -graph.dot";
    dot.Start();
    dot.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: The .dot file mustn't start with a "-"

Comment: You might also want to set the [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AxelKemper I removed the "-"/ still doesn't run.

Comment: @ChrisK i set the dir. like this: dot.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory=@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\"; still did not create my picture.

Answer (score 0):

Run from the cmd, adding /C to the beggining of your argument

```
using (var dot = new Process())
{
    dot.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // Run process as admin.
    dot.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    dot.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dot -Tpng -o graph.png -graph.dot";
    dot.Start();
    dot.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the Working Directory, so the file is probably generated but in somewhere like windows32 or similar default location.

Try the following

```
using (var dot = new Process())
{
    dot.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // Run process as admin.
    dot.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe";
    dot.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\ProgramData"; # or some other location you can write to
    dot.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Tpng -o graph.png -graph.dot";
    dot.Start();
    dot.WaitForExit();
}
```